# PHP faster image creation from base64

Tags: php, optimization, base64

I'im working on a project that generates an html content and converts it into canvas then saves it with PHP to the server, This process takes more than 15 secondes to be done which is a huge amount of time for visitors to wait, 
Is there anyway to make image creation from base64 files faster ? And what about server configuration what can I upgrade to make my server does this upload quicker ? Thanks .

This is the function code that generates the image, The thing is that users need to wait for canvas to be created then for the ajax request that sends image to the server which makes it about 17 secondes .

```
    function base64ToImage($base64_string, $output_file) 
{
      $file = fopen($output_file, "wb");

      $data = explode(',', $base64_string);

      fwrite($file, base64_decode($data[1]));
      fclose($file);

     return $output_file;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code so we can see what you're doing and how to speed it up. There's no way we can help with out a complete question.

Comment: @PatrickSimard Added the code, thanks .

Answer (score 0):

When an operation is too long to do immediately, you can defer it at a later time when the server was less load using a cron job. In the mean time, you  can save the string to DB (should be very fast) and just output it in the img tag

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, HwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

If this is not faster, then the problem is not saving the image but getting it from the source.

Comment: That would be a good idea, But I can't apply it because I need to generate a facebook share url for the user that includes the path of the image in the server and an id retrieved with the same ajax request after the upload is complet  .

Comment: You can still do this if your stream the base64 in a different php page and use that as the source of your image.The image stream can be from base64 code or directly from the image depending on if it was converted yet or not. Same URL for both. something like /imgstream.php?imgToken=1d485e4w

Comment: The thing, The share is done with a link that contains an id that is retrieved from the ajax request as well, Beside this, When users click on share button they need to see the uploaded image, In this case it would be blank since the image is not uploaded yet and it's just an expected link, Therefore the majority wouldn't share their results unless they see the image they're going to share ...

Comment: Then, in that case, you should put a loading icon with a "please wait" message. You could take a look at your server load while the action is happening and see if you have an unusual spike. If you do, then you might need more processing power. Also, take a look at your ram usage.

Comment: Im already putting a handler message ... what I need to know is the server configuration that would make this process of image creation faster .

Comment: Are you on a windows server or linux server?

Comment: I'm on a linux server .

Comment: use the linux command 'top' to monitor sever load as the event is going on. That should put you on the right track. You can also use 'vmstat 3' to get a snaptop of current CPU, IO, processes, and memory usage.